# Implicit coercion of a value .. - AS3 OOP

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

ok, so field.as contains a field class, which contains a method that calls a method from another class (in another file.)

field.as

```
...
find_path.findPath(start_node, end_node, findConnectedNodes ) // I am getting the error here
...
```

find_path.as has a method called findPath.

```
public static function findPath(firstNode:Node, destinationNode:Node,  connectedNodeFunction:Function ):Array{
....
```

the error I'm getting (getting the same error twice):

```
-1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type Node.
-1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type Node.
```

Comment: How do you declare the `start_node` and `end_node` variables?

Comment: in the class i.e. public var start_node:Node, end_node:Node;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not have declared the type of `start_node` and `end_node`.

Declare those variables as

```
[private / public / protected] var start_node:Node, end_node:Node;
```

Alternatively, call the function as

```
find_path.findPath(start_node as Node, end_node as Node, findConnectedNodes )
```

Comment: ok, thanks mate. the second method worked. however, I am not sure why you have to do this, can you please explain? thanks @Pranav Hosangadi

Comment: @dgamma3 you need to do this to explicitly cast `start_node` and `end_node` which you defined as `Object`s to the `Node` type. This tells the compiler that the argument you are supplying is definitely of the class `Node`. It would have been better to declare the variables to be of the class `Node` to take advantage of the strongly typed nature of Flash